# python 3.5 syntaxerror WITH parenthesis and quotations

Tags: python

I'm rather new to programming but when I print for example:

```
>>>print("Vladimir")
                  ^
```

I get:

> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

I don't understand why the quotes are invalid. I do have to push the quote key twice  for them to appear on screen, idk if that has anything to do with anything. any ideas will definitely help

Comment: Can you post the code around it? It is fine, I'm guessing some surrounding code is causing an error

Comment: >>>print("Vladimir")                                                                                                  SytaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: Are you using English or other language ?

Comment: @Philbus Can you edit your original post to show the entire code you have? Is there more than just this print statement? Thanks.

Comment: Was it copy and pasted in? Some encoding types need to be declared at the top of your file, for example if you're using UTF8 and it can't convert it, or converts it improperly this error is thrown too.

Comment: it wasn't copy and pasted, I have python 3.7 on my Mac and python 3.5 on my raspberry pi 3, it keeps giving me a syntax error on 3.5 but will print just fine on m y mac

Comment: It prints fine in 3.6.4; I'd still suspect either an encoding error or perhaps surrounding code or a typo; is there any other code above it you're trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Raspberry locale issue. You have to change keyboard layout.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=24751

> Sounds like you have selected a layout where the quotes are dead keys, for typing accents. Perhaps "English (US, international with dead keys)" instead of plain "English (US)"?